# Difference between executing multiple commands with && and ;

Tags: bash, shell

What's the difference between executing multiple commands with `&&` and `;`?

Examples:

```
echo "Hi\!" && echo "How are you?"
```

and

```
echo "Hi\!"; echo "How are you?"
```

Comment: Don't agree on the duplicate. That question doesn't even mention `;` at all, nor do any of the answers.

Comment: @Patrick - I understand you disagreeing, but I still think it's a dup. It talks about everything this one does, and though it doesn't specifically mention `;` the meaning of `;` is implied, since it's the alternative.

Comment: @slm I don't agree that the meaning of `;` is implied. For people that are familiar with programming, sure. But for newcomers? Not so much.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In the shell, `&&` and `;` are similar in that they both can be used to terminate commands. The difference is `&&` is also a conditional operator. With `;` the following command is always executed, but with `&&` the later command is only executed if the first succeeds.

```
false; echo "yes"   # prints "yes"
true; echo "yes"    # prints "yes"
false && echo "yes" # does not echo
true && echo "yes"  # prints "yes"
```

Newlines are interchangeable with `;` when terminating commands.

Comment: `||` is the opposite of `&&`: the RHS is executed if the LHS does not succeed: `false || echo yes # prints "yes"`

Comment: This accepted answer might also point out another difference being that with `&&` the linked commands form a compound command which is jointly backgrounded subsequent `&` whereas the `;` being two sequential commands will wait for completion of the first command before a trailing `&` will background the second command. `sleep 5s && sleep 5s & echo "waited 0s"` vs `"sleep 5s; sleep 5s & echo "waited 5s"`

Answer (score 4):

`&&` and `||` are boolean operators. && is the logical AND operator, and bash uses [short cut evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), so the second command is only executed if there is the chance that the whole expression can be true. If the first command is considered false (returned with a nonzero exit code), the whole AND-expression can never become true, so there is no need to evaluate the second command.

The same logic applies analogously to the logical OR, ||: if the first command is successful, the whole OR-expression will become true, so no need to evaluate the second command.