# What is the difference between the use of ; and executing a script

Tags: shell, command-line

I'm using `bash` as my main shell, but it's an open question and responses for shells others than `bash` are very welcome.

If I'm typing interactively

```
#original line 
#wget http://something.com && unzip something && mv -f something /home/poney/ 
#new line
wget http://something.com ; unzip something ; mv -f something /home/poney/
```

Does it make any difference in term of execution pile, order, memory, interpretation, permission compare to a script that contains those line:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget http://something.com
unzip something 
mv -f something /home/poney/
```

#### PS:

except the fact that executing a script is shorter than typing 3 command in a row obviously.

Comment: I'm not really convince about the duplicate because I'm also asking about pur scripting which is in my opinion different than interactive shell.

Comment: Related - [Difference between executing multiple commands with && and ;](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100704/difference-between-executing-multiple-commands-with-and)

Comment: @Kiwy But you did change the title completely. It is much more clear now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there is a big difference.  `&&` is *short-circuiting*, so the subsequent command would be executed only if the previous one returned with an exit code of `0`.

Quoting from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> *expression1* `&&` *expression2*
>
> ```
> True if both expression1 and expression2 are true.
> ```

On the other hand, a script containing

```
expression1
expression2
```

would execute the second expression even if the first failed.  (Unless you specified the script to exit on error by saying `set -e`.)

---

EDIT: Regarding your comment whether:

```
command1; command2
```

is the same as:

```
command1
command2
```

The answer is *usually*.  Bash parses an entire statement block before evaluating any of it. A ; doesn't cause the previous command to be evaluated. If the previous command were to have an effect on how the subsequent one would be parsed, then you'd notice the difference.

Consider a file containing aliases, lets call it `alias`, with an entry:

```
alias f="echo foo"
```

Now consider a script containing:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
source ./alias
f
```

and another one containing:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases; source ./alias; f
```

then you might think that both would produce the same output.

The answer is NO.  The first one would produce `foo` but the second one would report:

```
... f: command not found
```

To clarify further, it's not `expand_aliases` that's causing the problem.  The problem is due to the fact that a statement like:

```
alias f="echo foo"; f
```

would be *parsed* in one go.  The shell doesn't really know what `f` is, this causes the parser to choke.

Comment: OK then my qeustion should have been with `command ; command2; command3`

Comment: @Kiwy You mean `;` instead of `&&`?

Comment: so indeed the context of execution make the execution of a script and an interactive script behave differently mainly because of bash variable ?

Comment: @Kiwy Environment variable?

Comment: well variable related to the execution env ? is it unclear (maybe i'm using a french formulation) ?

Comment: Could you explain _why_? It is something to do with aliases being available only after they've been read but why is `;` not enough? Why is the new line necessary?

Comment: @terdon That's how the parser works.  A simpler example is `alias foo="echo bar"; foo`.

Comment: @terdon Another example is `shopt -s extglob; echo foo.@(bar)`.  When separated by newline, it'd work but not if separated by a `;`.

Comment: I know, I tried that and it works only with a newline. My question is why, I had always thought that `;` is the equivalent of a newline in a script.

Comment: @terdon Bash parses an entire statement block before evaluating any of it.  A `;` doesn't cause the previous command to be _evaluated_.  As such, the parser chokes on encountering an unknown command.

Comment: Ah! _That's_ what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @terdon You _knew_ that, didn't you?

Comment: Yes dammit, but had only encountered it in the context of function definitions and it didn't click on this example. Obvious in hindsight.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `&&` is condition. Command behind will be started only if the previous one returns `0` (ends without an error). On the other hand your script hasn't this control so if eg. wget ends with error it will continue and try to unzip and move nothing..

Onliner for your script is:

```
wget http://something.com ; unzip something ; mv -f something /home/poney/
```

Comment: does the `semi colon` in this case are the same as the jumpline in my script ?

Comment: @Kiwy, yes it is.

Answer (score 2):

Another difference to the one mentioned is that your shell script runs in a separate shell, therefore any changes to the environment won't propagate out. For example, if you type in your interactive shell

```
test -f foo && file=foo || file=other
```

then your interactive shell will contain a variable `file` (which you can read with `$file`) containing `foo` if the file foo exists and is a regular file, and `other` otherwise. Now if you put the same in a shell script and call that from your interactive shell, then the variable `file` in your interactive shell will not be set (but of course inside your shell script it will be set, so you can use it in further commands therein).